# How to not open event modal dialog of past event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am facing a problem with the implementation of the [jquery full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/). When clicking on a past event the modal opens but it shouldn't.

Only for current and future events should open a modal dialog.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    var eventEnd = moment(event.end);
    var NOW = moment();
    if (eventEnd.diff(NOW, 'seconds') <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
},
```

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: What modal are you using, bootstrap or? And do you have the modal data already rendered somewhere or is that also something you need to add to eventRender ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the `eventClick` handler for that:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  alert('You clicked the Event: ' + calEvent.title);
}
```

[Here's the working demo](https://codepen.io/benaloney/pen/zMwRrx?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

`event.end` is already a moment. The [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) mentions this (read the "end" section where it says it will become a moment throughout the API). You don't need to wrap it in another moment.

And if you want to compare it to another moment, [isSameOrAfter()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/) is a lot easier to use than diff()

Now a straight change to your existing code would look like this:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.end.isSameOrAfter(moment()) {
      //here you can place your code to attach a modal popup to the event
    }
},
```

Alternatively, if that's not how you are needing to define your modal, perhaps it would be better to use [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) instead - so when the user clicks the event, at that time you make the decision whether to display the modal or not. That might make more sense (in eventRender you'd probably still need some code to *define* the popup though).